# Questions regarding UK Visitor Visa in 2021

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am an Indian citizen, planning to visit my friend in UK during April-May 2021. I have couple of questions that I would like to ask.

1. I would have to self-isolate in UK for 10 days, Where do I need to isolate ? Can I isolate at my friend's place ? My friend is staying in a room inside a rented flat where other flat mates are also staying in their own rooms.
2. What should be the ideal duration of the visit ? Last year in March 2020, I applied for UK Visitor visa for 10 days. My Visa was issued but I couldn't travel due to Covid-19.
3. What are the chances for visa issuance ? I am only going to visit my friend and have no plans to visit any tourist places.

Comment: At this time it makes a big difference from which country/area you come how you need to quarantine. And chances for visa are speculation but the UK is in the middle of a health emergency and not welcoming visitors right now.

Comment: @Willeke They should have suspended the Visitor visa but they haven't.

Comment: There are still valid reasons to visit the UK, if very few, so suspending the visa is not the right thing to do. But visiting 'a friend' is likely not strong enough a reason.

Comment: @Willeke should I wait until Jun 21, 2021 then ?

Comment: I think you should plan travel no earlier but likely much later, as it is not at all sure travel will be back to normal any time soon. (I personally have a good reason to want to be in the UK in September but have not taken any steps in organizing the travel, as it is still to unsure.)

Comment: People are getting visitor visas to visit friends and family. I saw lot of refusals as well during past 6 months but they were mostly due to finances and 'tourism'. 
UK has also forced 10 days quarantine with Covid tests on Day 2 and Day 8 of your isolation since Feb 15, 2021 along with a negative Covid test report before you even travel to UK

Comment: The possible return of international travel for UK citizens is scheduled for May 17 and the earliest date by which all legal restrictions are hoped to be removed is 21 June. That doesn’t necessarily mean that there won’t still be restrictions on entry/quarantine similar to now https://www.gov.uk/guidance/how-to-quarantine-when-you-arrive-in-england I agree with @Willeke, it’s still too early to plan what sounds like a relatively short visit (given the distance) purely to visit a friend, and spend a significant portion of the visit in isolation

Comment: @Traveller it is possible to isolate in the same household where your friend is living as per the gov.uk latest updates

Comment: @Aak Maybe, however during your quarantine you are supposed to stay away from other people and not use shared areas. So during your quarantine you would have to stay in your own room and ideally have your own bathroom facilities

Comment: @Traveller so in that case I would require a separate room in the flat where my friend is staying or book a hotel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: India is not currently on the ‘red list’. When you arrive in England you must travel directly to the place you’re staying and not leave until 10 days have passed. You are allowed to stay with friends; you must quarantine in one place for the full quarantine period, where you can have food and other necessities delivered, and it must be at the address you provided on the passenger locator form.

You should avoid contact with other people during quarantine. This typically means staying in a separate room from other people, and ideally avoiding use of shared areas such as bathroom/kitchen.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/how-to-quarantine-when-you-arrive-in-england

Q2: There is no ‘ideal duration’. You need to demonstrate that you are a genuine visitor who will leave the UK at the end of your planned stay.  Typically that means that your reason for visiting makes sense, you have sufficient funds to cover the likely costs of the trip (and that cost is in proportion to your financial circumstances), and you can prove a compelling reason to return to your country of residence.  https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor

Q3: No-one can predict your chances, however the fact that your previous application was approved is a positive sign, unless your circumstances have significantly changed since then.